# plsq collection type definition

Tags: plsql, oracle12c, plsqldeveloper

I was trying to do insert based on the instruction provided in this [site](https://www.akadia.com/services/ora_bulk_insert.html).

I can run this example

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_proc (p_array_size IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 100)
IS
TYPE ARRAY IS TABLE OF all_objects%ROWTYPE;
l_data ARRAY;

CURSOR c IS SELECT * FROM all_objects;

BEGIN
    OPEN c;
    LOOP
    FETCH c BULK COLLECT INTO l_data LIMIT p_array_size;

    FORALL i IN 1..l_data.COUNT
    INSERT INTO t1 VALUES l_data(i);

    EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c;
END test_proc;
/
```

Similarly, I have changed the table name for real use as below.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_proc (p_array_size IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 100)
IS
TYPE ARRAY IS TABLE OF web.salesline%ROWTYPE;
l_data ARRAY;

CURSOR c IS SELECT * FROM web.salesline;

BEGIN
    OPEN c;
    LOOP
    FETCH c BULK COLLECT INTO l_data LIMIT p_array_size;

    FORALL i IN 1..l_data.COUNT
    INSERT INTO t2 VALUES l_data(i);

    EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c;
END test_proc;
/
```

But I'm getting following error, even though the table exists and accessing from the schema I was running.

```
SQL> show errors
Errors for PROCEDURE :

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
6/4      PL/SQL: Item ignored
6/34     PLS-00201: identifier 'WEB.SALESLINE' must be declared
11/7     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
16/9     PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
20/5     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
20/40    PLS-00597: expression 'OBJECTTABLE$' in the INTO list is of wrong
         type

23/5     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
23/27    PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

Comment: Can you create any procedure at all using `web.salesline`? As you are connecting as `web` anyway, does it make any difference if you omit the hardcoded schema name (it's generally good practice anyway).

Comment: This would be used only for development, so typically run from different schema. I tried to create a synonym for that table to run without 'web' but still fails with same error.

Comment: In the example above that is failing, is the procedure created in the `web` schema? If not, `web` will need to grant `select` privilege to the procedure owner. (This applies for any reference to objects in another schema, not just  for collection type definitions, which is why I asked whether you could compile any procedure referring to `web.salesline`.)

Comment: the procedure (`devuser`)owner has `dba` role so he has `select` privilege as well.

Comment: No, he doesn't :) Stored PL/SQL doesn't use roles.

Comment: I just tried `select` on the `web.salesline` from user `devuser` and it is working. What `grants` i need to provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the procedure is created in the `web` schema, you are referring to another schema's table, and so that schema needs to give you direct permission to use it. Note that there are no roles in stored procedure.

As the `WEB` user:

```
grant select on salesline to devuser;
```

(or whatever schema the procedure resides in).

Typically we try to avoid hardcoding schema names and instead manage these references using synonyms, so as `DEVUSER`:

```
create or replace synonym salesline for web.salesline;
```

Roles come back into play if you define the procedure `authid current_user` (the default is `authid definer`), however this is generally not a good idea for procedures that perform DML.